# More efficient way of selecting faces in a pattern?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to select a series of faces in a pattern like this:

[image]

I was hoping someone on here had a more efficient way of doing this sort of thing without having to select each face manually.

Comment: Maybe you should more anticipate how to model your object, how does your reference object look like?

Comment: Hello. It's still cumbersome but I think you'll get there faster by selecting everything and ALT + SHIFT + click on face border to deselect every other column and row

Comment: Sounds like the job for an array modifier rather than manual modelling